# Appium - application must be signed with a developer identity

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, appium

i have an application which i want to open through applium, after creating an adhoc ipa putting in valid provisioning profiles and developer certificates in both target and project build settings .

the error log i am getting is as follows :

```
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.optimus.btr was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments

info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] We exceeded the number of retries allowed for           instruments to successfully start; failing launch
info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
```

Any help regarding how to fix this issue would be much appreciated , many thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the only workaround i was able to manage was install the application onto the iOS device before starting appium tests and ,the run tests with appium, this will sort out issues with fruitstrap and instruments crashed on startup  crash

Comment: i can run the application from appium using the .app file from the xcode project after building the application , but i can't from the .app file which you get from the .ipa file. Used that as work around .